# Debian - `apt` showing out-of-date package for `stable` release

Tags: debian, apt

I'm running Debian 12 and noticed the following output:

```
$ apt list --all-versions firefox-esr
Listing... Done
firefox-esr/unstable 115.5.0esr-1 amd64
firefox-esr/stable-security 115.5.0esr-1~deb12u1 amd64
firefox-esr/testing 115.4.0esr-1 amd64
firefox-esr/stable,now 102.15.1esr-1~deb12u1 amd64 [installed]
```

This suggests that `stable`'s latest version of firefox is 102 (I just ran `sudo apt update` with no errors or warnings).  However, the Debian site claims the `stable` version is 115 [1].

Why am I getting an old version, then, in my `stable` results?  Here's my `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/stable.list`:

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable-security main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable-security main


deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main
```

[1] https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=firefox-esr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Chris Davies' answer, I ensured that all packages were included for `stable`, `stable-security`, and `stable-updates`, but still had this issue.  I realize now that Debian treats each of these as separate upstreams (which is obvious, but I guess I was confused since they're all "stable" and all listed in the same file).  I had `.pref` files  in  `/etc/apt/preferences.d` for `stable`, `unstable`, `testing`, etc., but not `stable-security` or `stable-updates`, so that seems to be why those were never getting picked up.  I did `sudo cp /etc/apt/preferences.d/stable.pref /etc/apt/preferences.d/stable-security.pref`, `sudo cp /etc/apt/preferences.d/stable.pref /etc/apt/preferences.d/stable-updates.pref`, tweaked those two new files as appropriate (gave slightly higher priorities and added `-update` and `-security`), and then re-ran `sudo apt update`.  Now I'm getting the expected results!

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please remember to ✔ accept it

Answer (score 3):

The stable version as released was (presumably) 102. The version in the stable security repository is 115. That this is the current supported version is identified on the [packages page for stable](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/firefox-esr) using large red text, "security". It's also identified in your list of package matches:

> ```
> firefox-esr/stable-security 115.5.0esr-1~deb12u1 amd64
> firefox-esr/stable,now 102.15.1esr-1~deb12u1 amd64 [installed]
> ```

I notice that you're not receiving security updates for several of your repository options. If you're listing `stable main contrib non-free non-free-firmware` for "stable" you should also provide the same list for "stable-security" and possible even "stable-updates":

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://security.debian.org/debian-security stable-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stable-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

Fix your `apt` repository configuration and then use `apt upgrade` and `apt update`